# Server side URL returns empty response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php file that returns a result that is JSON encoded. Im using:

```
$.GET("thephpfile.php",function(data){
     ipaddress = data['ip_address'];
     document.write(ipaddress)
});
```

"thephpfile.php" is in the same folder as the javascript page. Currently, I get a blank page. But when I add full path it works like this:

```
 $.GET("http://locahost/thephpfile.php",function(data){
     ipaddress = data['ip_address'];
     document.write(ipaddress)
});
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: add a closing `"` after the file location.. `$.GET("http://blah/phpfile.php", function...`

Comment: fixed it, but thats not the reason for the error anyway...

Comment: add a leading slash: `$.GET("/thephpfile.php"` this will make the path absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use following code for the solutions.

```
<?php
    define("ROOT_WWW","http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ."/yourprojectname/");
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajax_folder="<?= ROOT_WWW ?>";
</script>


$.GET(ajax_folder+"thephpfile.php",function(data){
 ipaddress = data['ip_address'];
 document.write(ipaddress)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.GET("/thephpfile.php",function(data){
       ipaddress = data['ip_address'];
       document.write(ipaddress)
  });
```